# Cannot import patterns django while deploying(pythonanywhere)

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

AoA
   I am trying to deploy my project(which i made on localhost) to [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) I have followed all instruction( installed django 1.5, set up the wsgi.py file and changed all every file( views, urls, models, settings ) according to pythonanywhere...
   Now the problem is of setting the python 2.7( path on virtualenv ) when I reload app and navigate to my site, I get error something like this -> http://saadfast.pythonanywhere.com/

whereas the config file wsgi file is ->

```
activate_this = '/home/saadfast/.virtualenvs/django15/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/saadfast/Wikipedia')

path = '/home/saadfast/Wikipedia'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Wikipedia.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import Wikipedia.views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'Wikipedia.views.home_Page'),
     url(r'^home/$', 'Wikipedia.views.home_Page',name='home_view'),
     url(r'^search/$', 'Wikipedia.views.search_PageItems', name='search_view'),
     url(r'^article/(?P<item>[-\w]+)/$', 'Wikipedia.views.articleItem', name='article_view'),
     url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'Wikipedia.views.article'),
)
```

the python environment path it is showing on debug page is something /usr/local....
but there is no /usr folder in the pythonanywhere directory, the directory structure is something like this

```
/
 /home
 /temp
 /var
```

Comment: The python path on the error message on the page that you reference does not include any virtualenv directories, so the activation of your virtualenv is not working. That means you're running with the default Django version and not 1.5.

Comment: So, how can I set it to virtualenv path?

Comment: okay....got it...its working now